# cudaMemCpy returning cudaInvalidData

Tags: c++, cuda, memcpy

I have written a method that is called from a .cpp file for the purpose of running cudaMemcpy. The method is below:

```
void copy_to_device(uint32_t *host, uint32_t *device, int size)
{
    cudaError_t ret; 
    ret = cudaMemcpy(device, host, size*sizeof(uint32_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 

    if(ret == cudaErrorInvalidValue)
        printf("1!\n"); 
    else if(ret == cudaErrorInvalidDevicePointer)
        printf("2!\n"); 
    else if(ret == cudaErrorInvalidMemcpyDirection)
        printf("3!\n"); 
}
```

my .cpp file calls it like this:

```
uint32_t *input_device;
device_malloc(input_device, INPUT_HEIGHT*INPUT_WIDTH);
uint32_t  *oneDinput = TwoDtoOneD(input, INPUT_HEIGHT, INPUT_WIDTH); 
copy_to_device(oneDinput, input_device, INPUT_HEIGHT*INPUT_WIDTH);
```

All that TwoDtoOneD does is take in a 2D array and convert it to a 1D array and return it. Whenever I try and use `copy_to_device` method, it returns [cudaErrorInvalidValue](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__TYPES_g3f51e3575c2178246db0a94a430e0038.html) which isn't well documented on NVIDIA's website.  Do you guys happen to know what is wrong with the parameters I am passing to my function that is causing this error? It's causing issues down the road during kernel execution. If you need any more details, please ask.

Here's the method `device_malloc`:

```
void device_malloc(uint32_t *buffer, int size)
{
    cudaMalloc((void **) &buffer, size*sizeof(uint32_t)); 
}
```

Comment: @Tae-SungShin I hate not, but in my cuda code, I #include <stdint.h> which defines uint32_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
uint32_t *input_device;
device_malloc(input_device, INPUT_HEIGHT*INPUT_WIDTH);
```

Whatever `device_malloc` does, it does not modify the `input_device` value. That is, unless the first argument is a reference to pointer, but I am ready to bet it is not.

You need to change the first argument of `device_malloc` to a pointer to pointer, and call it like that:

```
device_malloc(&input_device, INPUT_HEIGHT*INPUT_WIDTH);
```

Or just have `device_malloc` return a pointer to the allocated memory.

To answer your question more directly, `cudaMemcpy` returns an error because its first argument, `device`, is not a valid device pointer, which CUDA runtime has a way of checking. It probably holds garbage value since you never initialize it due to the above issue.

As a side note and unrelated to the issue, you may want to use `cudaGetErrorString` funciton for a more convenient way to print out the status.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added the definition of the method `device_malloc` in my original post. I do give it a reference to that pointer in the first argument of `cudaMalloc`. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: This is not a reference to a pointer; this is the pointer itself. Value assigned to `buffer` by `cudaMalloc` is not assigned to `input_device` in the calling code.